# Is zero a solution for PDE (D'Alembert Formula)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, linear-pde

I have the PDE:

$u_{tt}=u_{xx},\quad 0<x<1,\,0<t<\infty \\ u(0,t)=0 \\ u(1,t)=\sin\,t \\ u(x,0)=u_t(x,0)=0,\quad 0<x<1$

When i used the D'Alembert formula i got $0$ because $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ (Initial function) is $0$
Am i wrong? But it's weird if the solution $u(x,t)=0$

Comment: Does $u(x,t) = 0$ satisfy the boundary condition at $x=1$?

D'Alembert's formula works when the spatial domain is $\mathbb R$; here the domain is bounded in space. In these cases, you can usually separate variables.

Comment: Yes the separation variables gives me $0$ too. Anyway thanks for the answer. But please to check this book "Linear Partial Differential Equation for Scientist and Engineer" written by Myint-U Derbanth. On page 136 The book says that we can use D'Alembert Solution on bounded space. It's called Vibration of Finite String with Fixed Ends. I confused with this book actually. Anyway if you want to check this book, you can download it on site "pdf drive". Please to help me. Or i missunderstood about this book?

Comment: Since I can't tell from your response, think about (just like the previous comment indicates) whether or not $u\equiv 0$ satisfy $u(0,1)=\sin t.$ Also, check what the boundary conditions are for the version of D'Albert's solution.

Comment: No, it's not satisfied because the solution doesn't have variable. What if i change the boundary conditions to homogeneous boundary conditions first? Like solving steady state and transient on Heat equation. Will it works?

Comment: I haven't looked at the book, but if you want to use the d'Alembert formula for a bounded domain, you need to break the domain up into different regions. Fixing $x$, in regions where $0 \le x-t \le 1$ and $0 \le x+t \le 1$ the characteristics have not yet hit the boundaries, but after $t$ gets large enough you need to start considering boundary conditions.

Comment: If you make the boundary conditions zero, then yes. This is because your initial and boundary conditions will now be all $0$, so $0$ will work.

Comment: Thaaankss. Finally.